# initials after State Senator or State Assemblyperson's name

Tags: meaning

what do the initials after a State Senator or State Assemblyperson's name mean?

example:  (R C IP RFM)

I'm guessing the first initial is for the party they belong to, but what about the others?  any thoughts?

Comment: Can you quote an example?  Please provide the name of the legislative body that the person is a member of.

Answer (score 2):

They are all party affiliations:

R — New York Republican Party
C — Conservative Party of New York
IP — Independence Party of New York State
RFM — Reform Party of New York

(New York is one of seven states that still practice [electoral fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_fusion) in the legislature.)